# How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have to write a program to calculate `a**b % c` where `b` and `c` are both very large numbers. If I just use `a**b % c`, it's really slow. Then I found that the built-in function `pow()` can do this really fast by calling `pow(a, b, c)`.
 I'm curious to know how does Python implement this? Or where could I find the source code file that implement this function?

Comment: The cpython source repo is at http://hg.python.org/cpython/

Comment: ...under _Objects/longobject.c:long_pow()_ (as JimB had already commented).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If `a`, `b` and `c` are integers, the implementation can be made more efficient by [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and reducing modulo `c` in each step, including the first one (i.e. reducing `a` modulo `c` before you even start).  This is what [the implementation of `long_pow()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/109fc2792a490ee5cd8a423e17d415fbdedec5c8/Objects/longobject.c#L4244-L4447) does indeed. The function has over two hundred lines of code, as it has to deal with reference counting, and it handles negative exponents and a whole bunch of special cases.

At its core, the idea of the algorithm is rather simple, though. Let's say we want to compute `a ** b` for positive integers `a` and `b`, and `b` has the binary digits `b_i`. Then we can write `b` as

```
b = b_0 + b1 * 2 + b2 * 2**2 + ... + b_k ** 2**k
```

ans `a ** b` as

```
a ** b = a**b0 * (a**2)**b1 * (a**2**2)**b2 * ... * (a**2**k)**b_k
```

Each factor in this product is of the form `(a**2**i)**b_i`. If `b_i` is zero, we can simply omit the factor. If `b_i` is 1, the factor is equal to `a**2**i`, and these powers can be computed for all `i` by repeatedly squaring `a`. Overall, we need to square and multiply `k` times, where `k` is the number of binary digits of `b`.

As mentioned above, for `pow(a, b, c)` we can reduce modulo `c` in each step, both after squaring and after multiplying.

Comment: Why can we reduce by modulo c in each step?

Comment: @BenSandler: Because _a_ ≡ _a'_ (mod _c_) and _b_ ≡ _b'_ (mod _c_) imply _ab_ ≡ _a'b'_ (mod _c_), or in other words, it doesn't matter whether you first reduce _a_ and _b_ modulo _c_ and then multiply them, or multiply them first and then reduce modulo _c_.  See [the Wikipedia article on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n).

Comment: Note that `long_pow` is now defined at another line in that file: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4246

Comment: @JohanC I've updated the link to include the commit hash, so it doesn't get out of date anymore.

Answer (score 40):

You might consider the following two implementations for computing `(x ** y) % z` quickly.

**In Python:**

```
def pow_mod(x, y, z):
    "Calculate (x ** y) % z efficiently."
    number = 1
    while y:
        if y & 1:
            number = number * x % z
        y >>= 1
        x = x * x % z
    return number
```

**In C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long pow_mod(unsigned short x, unsigned long y, unsigned short z)
{
    unsigned long number = 1;
    while (y)
    {
        if (y & 1)
            number = number * x % z;
        y >>= 1;
        x = (unsigned long)x * x % z;
    }
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", pow_mod(63437, 3935969939, 20628));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Noctis, I tried running your Python implementation and got this:TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''  ---- As I'm learning Python right now, I thought you might have an idea about this error (a search suggests it might be a bug but I'm thinking that there's a quick workaround)

Comment: @stackuser: It appears to be working fine in the following demonstration: http://ideone.com/sYzqZN

Comment: Can anyone explain why this solution works? I am having trouble understanding the logic behind this algorithm.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, what would be the benefit of this considering the native python `pow()` builtin function supports this as well and seems faster?
`>>> st_pow = 'pow(65537L, 767587L, 14971787L)
>>> st_pow_mod = 'pow_mod(65537L, 767587L, 14971787L)'
>>> timeit.timeit(st_pow)
4.510787010192871
>>> timeit.timeit(st_pow_mod, def_pow_mod)
10.135776996612549`

Comment: @Fabiano My function is not supposed to be used. It is simply an explanation of how Python works behinds the scenes without referring to its source in C. I was trying to answer **wong2's** question about how `pow` was implimented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about python, but if you need fast powers, you can use exponentiation by squaring:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

It's a simple recursive method that uses the commutative property of exponents.

Answer (score -1):

Line 1426 of [this file](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/mathmodule.c?revision=82221&view=markup) shows the Python code that implements math.pow, but basically it boils down to it calling the standard C library which probably has a highly optimized version of that function.

Python can be quite slow for intensive number-crunching, but [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) can give you a quite speed boost, it won't be as good as C code calling the standard library though.

Comment: `math.pow()` does't have the modulo argument, and isn't the same function as the builtin `pow()`. Also FYI, Psyco is getting pretty stale, and no 64-bit support. NumPy is great for serious math.

Answer (score -1):

Python uses C math libraries for general cases and its own logic for some of its concepts (such as infinity).

Answer (score -1):

**Implement pow(x,n) in Python**

```
def myPow(x, n):
        p = 1
        if n<0:
            x = 1/x
            n = abs(n)

        # Exponentiation by Squaring

        while n:
            if n%2:
                p*= x
            x*=x
            n//=2
        return p
```

**Implement pow(x,n,m) in Python**

```
def myPow(x,n,m):
            p = 1
            if n<0:
                x = 1/x
                n = abs(n)
            while n:
                if n%2:
                    p*= x%m
                x*=x%m
                n//=2
            return p
```

Checkout this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3Lt-EwR_Hw) for explanation