# Behavior of Python ** and % operators with big numbers

Tags: python, math, modulo

When I put in Python interpreter a ** b % c with large a (20 figures) b (4 figures) c (20 figures) I saw that Python calculates it pretty fast, almost like pow (a,b,c). I expect another behavior that Python first calculate a ** b then get the modulo (%) of result and such calculation will take significantly more time.

Where is the magic behind the scene?

Comment: You can use `pow` to calculate `(x ** y) % z` efficiently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/3371415#3371415

Answer (score 6):

If you are typing into the Python interpreter something like:

```
20937505974095709374 ** 3438
```

Then seeing a couple of seconds wait. Then trying:

```
20937505974095709374 ** 3438 % 6
```

And seeing **no** wait, and wondering why there is a difference, then the *delay* that you see in the first instance is actually the time your terminal takes to buffer and print the huge number you just created to the screen.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the issue, as you can see by assigning each calculation to a variable rather than printing it.

Answer (score 4):

20 figures is laughably small on a modern computer. Try 2000 figures and you might see a difference.

Also, this past question is related: [How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246856/how-did-python-implement-the-built-in-function-pow)

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic behind the scenes, other than Python supports arbitrary-precision integers, and is well-implemented.  It really did calculate a**b, then %c.

Answer (score 0):

Today's computers are amazingly fast, very complicated calculations can occur in what seems like no time at all. You need to repeat such calculations very many times to see the delay; I'd start with a million.