# power arguments in Python

Tags: python

Undertaking a task to Write a function power that accepts two arguments, a and b and calculates a raised to the power b.

Example

```
power(2, 3) => 8
```

Note: Don't use

```
2 ** 3
```

and don't use

```
Math.pow(2, 3)
```

I have tried this

```
def power(a,b):
    return eval(((str(a)+"*")*b)[:-1])
```

And it works but seems to fail one test which is to `return_1_when_exp_is_0`

and i also get the error

```
Unhandled Exception: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 0)
```

Please how do i solve this issue considering that i am new to python

Comment: if-else: if exp is 0, return 1 else return the result of a calculation.  You do not need to resort to using `eval`, either.

Comment: Are the arguments integers, or floating point?

Comment: @TomLynch i fill bad right now. Considered that but did it wrong thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop

```
x=1    
for i in range(b):
    x=x*a

print(x)
```

Comment: `a=2, b=3` prints `16` not `8`... I'm sure you meant to initialize `x=1`. Setting `x=1` also solves the `0` exponent ask, `a=<anything>.b=0` will print `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using eval is a terrible idea, but if you really wanted to then using `join()` would be a better way to create the string:

```
def power(a, b):
    return eval('*'.join([str(a)]*b))

>>> power(2, 3)
8
```

If you add `['1']` to the front then the `0` exponent behaves properly:

```
def power(a, b):
    return eval('*'.join(['1']+[str(a)]*b))

>>> power(2, 0)
1
```

However, this is simple to implement for integer exponents with a `for` loop:

```
def power(n, e):
    t = 1
    for _ in range(e):
        t *= n
    return t

>>> power(2, 3)
8
>>> power(2, 0)
1
```

You could also use `functools.reduce()` to do the same thing:

```
import functools as ft
import operator as op

def power(n, e):
    return ft.reduce(op.mul, [n]*e, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine

```
def power(a,b):
    if b == 0:
      return 1
    else:
      return eval(((str(a)+"*")*b)[:-1])
```

Comment: You should not use `eval` without explicit reason. Especially for pure math\algorithm task. Basically what you do here is just performing `b-1` multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

```
def power(theNumber, thePower):
#basically, multiply the number for power times

try:
    theNumber=int(theNumber)
    thePower=int(thePower)
    if theNumber == 0:
        return 0
    elif thePower == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return theNumber * power(theNumber,thePower-1)

except exception as err:
    return 'Only digits are allowed as input'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `eval` by all costs, especially when it's very simple to implement pure algorithmic efficient solution. Classic efficient algorithm is [Exponentiation_by_squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Instead of computing and multiplying numbers `n` times, you can always divide it to squares to archive logarithmic* complexity.
For example, for calculating `x^15`:

```
x^15 = (x^7)*(x^7)*x 
x^7 = (x^3)*(x^3)*x 
x^3 = x*x*x
```

Thus taking 6 multiplications instead of 14.

```
def pow3(x, n):
    r = 1
    while n:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            r *= x
            n -= 1
        x *= x
        n /= 2
    return r
```

Source: https://helloacm.com/exponentiation-by-squaring/

**Note**: it was not mentioned in the question, but everything above considers N to be positive integer. If your question was also covering fractional or negative exponent, suggested approach will not work "as is".

* Of course depends on length of x and complexity of multiplying, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for detailed complexity analysis.

Also may be interesting to check out following questions: [C solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/108959/1657819) or  [Python implementing pow() for exponentiation by squaring for very large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421311/python-implementing-pow-for-exponentiation-by-squaring-for-very-large-integers)

Answer (score -1):

```
def power(a, b):
  if b == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return a ** b
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good. Please add some explanation to it.

Comment: This does not answer the question, because it was explicitly mentioned in the text "do not use `**`"