# Modular exponentiation in C++

Tags: c++, modulo, exponentiation

Something is wrong in my code for modular exponentiation and I can't spot the problem despite of writing it three times when using two different sources of pseudocode. I've read other questions about  modular exponentiation in C++ on SE but that didn't help me.
Here is my last code, written by simpler but less optimal way I think :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// base ^ exponent mod modulus 
unsigned mulmod1(unsigned base, unsigned exponent, unsigned modulus) {
    int result = 1;
    while(exponent > 0){
        if(exponent % 2 == 1)
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
  return result;
}

int main(){

//9688563^45896 mod 71 = 30
//12^53 mod 7 = 3

cout<<mulmod1(9688563,45896 ,71)<<"\n";   //gives 10 instead of 30
cout<<mulmod1(12,53,7)<<"\n";             //gives correct answer 3

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I've added print statements but I it didn't help and now I start to think I don't understand something with idea of modular exponentiation or with C++ itself

Comment: You should find the simplest test-case that doesn't work, then add print statements to trace the value of every single variable on every single iteration, and compare them to a manual calculation.  As soon as there is a discrepancy, then you have found your bug.

Answer (score 4):

Sanitize the inputs to your function `mulmod1`! `unsigned` cannot hold `9688563*9688563`.
If you do this right, you 'only' need a data type that can hold `modulus * modulus` (and your input numbers, of course) to perform modular exponentiation correctly.

Comment: unsigned long long also, so I've to try another pseudocode for suitable for bigger numbers

Comment: @Qbik In case it wasn't clear, I was suggesting that you do `base = base % modulus` before doing any calculations on it...

Comment: I've just added this, something is still wrong mulmod1(9688563,45896 ,71) gives 20 instead of 30

Comment: Actually, I think 20 is the correct answer. You can try it in Python: `pow(9688563,45896,71)` yields `20`. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246856/2073257).