# Python Program Cannot Handle Large Numbers

Tags: python

So I have written a program (see below) to run a series of test cases and for each case determine if X exists for A≡X^2(modM) using [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). It works fine for small test cases, such as when A = 0 and M = 2 or A = 4 and M = 7, but when I consider larger test cases, such as when A = 83715323 and M = 118299443, the program just hangs on line 15 (shown below). Why is this program hanging? Is it a limit of python? Should I perhaps just redo it in something like C++?

**The Problem Line**

```
if((A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1) % M[case]) == 0:
```

**The Whole Program**

```
number_of_cases = int(raw_input())

A = []
M = []

for case in range(number_of_cases):
    A_M = raw_input().split()
    A.append(int(A_M[0]))
    M.append(int(A_M[1]))

for case in range(number_of_cases):

    solution_exists = 0

    if((A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1) % M[case]) == 0:
        print ("YES")
        break        

    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: Python can handle large numbers just fine. Question is: can your PC? You'll need enough memory to contain the **huge** integer you are constructing for the `(A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1)` expression. 83715323  to the power 59149720 requires 468631695 decimal digits (half a billion, roughly), so Python is asking your OS for just about all your memory. And the *swapping* that causes is what makes your program hang.

Comment: Hmmm, I have 16 gb of RAM and I'm running Fedora, but wholly crap that's big!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer calculated by `A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1)` can get very large very quickly. It will take a lot of time and memory to calculate this number using any language.

Instead, take advantage of Python's `pow` operator and its third argument, which allows for efficient modular exponentiation.

Try changing

```
if((A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1) % M[case]) == 0:
```

to

```
if pow(A[case], (M[case] - 1)/2 - 1, M[case]) == 0:
```

The large number `A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2) - 1)` is not calculated here: Python increments the power gradually and keeps track of the remainder modulo `M[case]` at each step.

Comment: I beat you by **nine** seconds, but your knowledge of python trumps my speediness. +1

Comment: but you also identified the problem and gave the useful wiki link :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are performing [modular exponentiation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

For that reason, you don't need to calculate `A[case]**((M[case] - 1)/2)` in one statement. This is likely what is causing your hang.

Use the fact that

```
x**(n) % m == {(x**(n-1) % m) * x} % m
```

i.e. you can calculate the remainder of `x^n` for **arbitrarily** large n without calculating `x^n` *directly* by multiplying then getting the remainder repeatedly.

Try *breaking up* the exponentiation (see the "[*Memory-efficient method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method)" section of the wiki article) and seeing if it's still slow.

My bet is that it isn't.

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer as well, but the simplest solution was the one put forward by ajcr. However this solution actually helped me to understand what I was doing and is more efficient.

Comment: @sparky2012 — thanks for the thought. I would hope that the python implementation of modular exponentiation basically does what I describe - it'd be a bit mad if it didn't. Maybe try both and compare? :)

Comment: Yeah, going to do that now.

Comment: Hmm. Just found this on SO: "[*How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246856/1364007)" (about modular exponentiation). It seems they basically do the same thing.