# How to find 2 to the power of an insanely big number modulo 10^9

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have an excessively big number (1500+) digits and I need to find 2 ** that number modulo 1_000_000_000 so I wrote this python:

```
n = 1
return_value = 2
while n < To_the_power_of:
    return_value *= 2
    return_value = return_value % 1_000_000_000 
    n += 1
```

This returns the correct value for smaller values, but takes too long for bigger values.

If the number is modulo 10 then you get this pattern which could be used.

```
2 ** 1 modulo 10 = 2
2 ** 2 modulo 10 = 4
2 ** 3 modulo 10 = 8
2 ** 4 modulo 10 = 6
2 ** 5 modulo 10 = 2
2 ** 6 modulo 10 = 4 
2 ** 7 modulo 10 = 8 
2 ** 8 modulo 10 = 6
```

I'm hoping that a similar pattern could be used to answer the original problem.

Comment: Did you try using larger moduloes? i.e. mod 100, 1000, etc. which can be computed easily?

Comment: Can any power of 2 modulo a power of 10 be 0 or an odd number? No.  That should be a big clue.

Comment: Your idea is good, why don't you use it: you are guaranteed that there will be a repeating pattern before the 10^9 th iteration...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried `(2 ** the_big_number) % 1000000000`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's an even worse way, much slower, a lot more memory hungry and requires a bigint implementation. You need [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for this purpose. [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496182/995714), [How did Python implement `pow(a, b, c)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246856/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know that the sequence will repeat.  You found the cycle of 4 for mod 10; now, just find it for a billion:

```
mod_billion = set()
pow_2 = 2
billion = 10**9

while pow_2 not in mod_billion:
    mod_billion.add(pow_2)
    pow_2 *= 2
    if pow_2 > billion:
        pow_2 -= billion

print (pow_2, len(mod_billion))
```

Three seconds later, we get:

```
512 1562508
```

Thus, this sequence repeats every 1562508 items.  To find your value for your given power:

```
cycle = 1562508
small_power = big_power % cycle
result = (2 ** small_power) % billion
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes about `10 ** 1500` iterations, which is indeed insanely long. A useful general technique is [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which will give you the result in about 4500 iterations.

If you want to follow the path of the @Prune's answer, you should go along the lines of Fermat's Little Theorem, specifically the [Euler's generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). `phi(1_000_000_000)` is easy to compute, because `10 ** 9 = (2 ** 9) * (5 ** 9)`, the product of 2 powers of primes.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand upon the cyclicality aspect of it :

```
        | 10^ 1 starts cycling at := 2^( 1)
                                           (                   2)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  1-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                                4
        | 0x                                                      4
        | 8#                                                      4
```

---

```
        | 10^ 2 starts cycling at := 2^( 2)
                                           (                   4)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  2-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                               20
        | 0x                                                     14
        | 8#                                                     24
```

---

```
        | 10^ 3 starts cycling at := 2^( 3)
                                           (                   8)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  3-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                              100
        | 0x                                                     64
        | 8#                                                    144
```

---

```
        | 10^ 4 starts cycling at := 2^( 4)
                                           (                  16)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  4-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                              500
        | 0x                                                    1F4
        | 8#                                                    764
```

---

```
        | 10^ 5 starts cycling at := 2^( 5)
                                           (                  32)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  5-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                             2500
        | 0x                                                    9C4
        | 8#                                                   4704
```

---

```
        | 10^ 6 starts cycling at := 2^( 6)
                                           (                  64)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  6-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                            12500
        | 0x                                                   30D4
        | 8#                                                  30324
```

---

```
        | 10^ 7 starts cycling at := 2^( 7)
                                           (                 128)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  7-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                            62500
        | 0x                                                   F424
        | 8#                                                 172044
```

---

```
        | 10^ 8 starts cycling at := 2^( 8)
                                           (                 256)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  8-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                           312500
        | 0x                                                  4C4B4
        | 8#                                                1142264
```

---

```
        | 10^ 9 starts cycling at := 2^( 9)
                                           (                 512)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^(  9-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                          1562500
        | 0x                                                 17D784
        | 8#                                                5753604
```

---

```
        | 10^10 starts cycling at := 2^(10)
                                           (                1024)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 10-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                          7812500
        | 0x                                                 773594
        | 8#                                               35632624
```

---

```
        | 10^11 starts cycling at := 2^(11)
                                           (                2048)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 11-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                         39062500
        | 0x                                                2540BE4
        | 8#                                              225005744
```

---

```
        | 10^12 starts cycling at := 2^(12)
                                           (                4096)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 12-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                        195312500
        | 0x                                                BA43B74
        | 8#                                             1351035564
```

---

```
        | 10^13 starts cycling at := 2^(13)
                                           (                8192)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 13-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                        976562500
        | 0x                                               3A352944
        | 8#                                             7215224504
```

---

```
        | 10^14 starts cycling at := 2^(14)
                                           (               16384)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 14-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                       4882812500
        | 0x                                              12309CE54
        | 8#                                            44302347124
```

---

```
        | 10^15 starts cycling at := 2^(15)
                                           (               32768)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 15-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                      24414062500
        | 0x                                              5AF3107A4
        | 8#                                           265714203644
```

---

```
        | 10^16 starts cycling at := 2^(16)
                                           (               65536)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 16-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                     122070312500
        | 0x                                             1C6BF52634
        | 8#                                          1615375223064
```

---

```
        | 10^17 starts cycling at := 2^(17)
                                           (              131072)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 17-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                     610351562500
        | 0x                                             8E1BC9BF04
        | 8#                                         10703362337404
```

---

```
        | 10^18 starts cycling at := 2^(18)
                                           (              262144)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 18-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                    3051757812500
        | 0x                                            2C68AF0BB14
        | 8#                                         54321274135424
```

---

```
        | 10^19 starts cycling at := 2^(19)
                                           (              524288)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 19-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                   15258789062500
        | 0x                                            DE0B6B3A764
        | 8#                                        336026654723544
```

---

```
        | 10^20 starts cycling at := 2^(20)
                                           (             1048576)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 20-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                   76293945312500
        | 0x                                           4563918244F4
        | 8#                                       2126162140442364
```

---

```
        | 10^21 starts cycling at := 2^(21)
                                           (             2097152)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 21-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                  381469726562500
        | 0x                                          15AF1D78B58C4
        | 8#                                      12657072742654304
```

---

```
        | 10^22 starts cycling at := 2^(22)
                                           (             4194304)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 22-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                 1907348632812500
        | 0x                                          6C6B935B8BBD4
        | 8#                                      66153446556135724
```

---

```
        | 10^23 starts cycling at := 2^(23)
                                           (             8388608)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 23-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                 9536743164062500
        | 0x                                         21E19E0C9BAB24
        | 8#                                     417031701446725444
```

---

```
        | 10^24 starts cycling at := 2^(24)
                                           (            16777216)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 24-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                                47683715820312500
        | 0x                                         A968163F0A57B4
        | 8#                                    2513201307702453664
```

---

```
        | 10^25 starts cycling at := 2^(25)
                                           (            33554432)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 25-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                               238418579101562500
        | 0x                                        34F086F3B33B684
        | 8#                                   15170206747314733204
```

---

```
        | 10^26 starts cycling at := 2^(26)
                                           (            67108864)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 26-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                              1192092895507812500
        | 0x                                       108B2A2C28029094
        | 8#                                  102131242605000510224
```

---

```
        | 10^27 starts cycling at := 2^(27)
                                           (           134217728)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 27-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                              5960464477539062500
        | 0x                                       52B7D2DCC80CD2E4
        | 8#                                  512676455631003151344
```

---

```
        | 10^28 starts cycling at := 2^(28)
                                           (           268435456)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 28-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                             29802322387695312500
        | 0x                                      19D971E4FE8401E74
        | 8#                                 3166270744775020017164
```

---

```
        | 10^29 starts cycling at := 2^(29)
                                           (           536870912)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 29-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                            149011611938476562500
        | 0x                                      813F3978F89409844
        | 8#                                20117634570761120114104
```

---

```
        | 10^30 starts cycling at := 2^(30)
                                           (          1073741824)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 30-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                            745058059692382812500
        | 0x                                     2863C1F5CDAE42F954
        | 8#                               120617017534665620574524
```

---

```
        | 10^31 starts cycling at := 2^(31)
                                           (          2147483648)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 31-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                           3725290298461914062500
        | 0x                                     C9F2C9CD04674EDEA4
        | 8#                               623713116320214723557244
```

---

```
        | 10^32 starts cycling at := 2^(32)
                                           (          4294967296)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 32-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                          18626451492309570312500
        | 0x                                    3F1BDF10116048A5934
        | 8#                              3743367610021300442454464
```

---

```
        | 10^33 starts cycling at := 2^(33)
                                           (          8589934592)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 33-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                          93132257461547851562500
        | 0x                                   13B8B5B5056E16B3BE04
        | 8#                             23561326650126702654737004
```

---

```
        | 10^34 starts cycling at := 2^(34)
                                           (         17179869184)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 34-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                         465661287307739257812500
        | 0x                                   629B8C891B267182B614
        | 8#                            142467062110662316140533024
```

---

```
        | 10^35 starts cycling at := 2^(35)
                                           (         34359738368)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 35-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                        2328306436538696289062500
        | 0x                                  1ED09BEAD87C0378D8E64
        | 8#                            755023372554174006743307144
```

---

```
        | 10^36 starts cycling at := 2^(36)
                                           (         68719476736)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 36-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                       11641532182693481445312500
        | 0x                                  9A130B963A6C115C3C7F4
        | 8#                           4641141345435154042560743764
```

---

```
        | 10^37 starts cycling at := 2^(37)
                                           (        137438953472)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 37-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                       58207660913467407226562500
        | 0x                                 3025F39EF241C56CD2E7C4
        | 8#                          30045747173622034255464563704
```

---

```
        | 10^38 starts cycling at := 2^(38)
                                           (        274877906944)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 38-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                      291038304567337036132812500
        | 0x                                 F0BDC21ABB48DB201E86D4
        | 8#                         170275604152732215544007503324
```

---

```
        | 10^39 starts cycling at := 2^(39)
                                           (        549755813888)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 39-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                     1455191522836685180664062500
        | 0x                                4B3B4CA85A86C47A098A224
        | 8#                        1131664625026503304364046121044
```

---

```
        | 10^40 starts cycling at := 2^(40)
                                           (       1099511627776)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 40-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                     7275957614183425903320312500
        | 0x                               178287F49C4A1D6622FB2AB4
        | 8#                        5701207751161120726304276625264
```

---

```
        | 10^41 starts cycling at := 2^(41)
                                           (       2199023255552)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 41-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                    36379788070917129516601562500
        | 0x                               758CA7C70D7292FEAEE7D584
        | 8#                       35306247616065624457725671752604
```

---

```
        | 10^42 starts cycling at := 2^(42)
                                           (       4398046511104)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 42-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                   181898940354585647583007812500
        | 0x                              24BBF46E3433CDEF96A872B94
        | 8#                      222737506706414746757455241625624
```

---

```
        | 10^43 starts cycling at := 2^(43)
                                           (       8796093022208)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 43-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                   909494701772928237915039062500
        | 0x                              B7ABC627050305ADF14A3D9E4
        | 8#                     1336536142340500602655742450754744
```

---

```
        | 10^44 starts cycling at := 2^(44)
                                           (      17592186044416)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 44-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                  4547473508864641189575195312500
        | 0x                             3965ADEC3190F1C65B67334174
        | 8#                     7131326754143103616145554714640564
```

---

```
        | 10^45 starts cycling at := 2^(45)
                                           (      35184372088832)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 45-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                 22737367544323205947875976562500
        | 0x                            11EFC659CF7D4B8DFC904004744
        | 8#                    43677062634757522706774440400043504
```

---

```
        | 10^46 starts cycling at := 2^(46)
                                           (      70368744177664)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 46-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                113686837721616029739379882812500
        | 0x                            59AEDFC10D7279C5EED14016454
        | 8#                   263273376020656236342756642400262124
```

---

```
        | 10^47 starts cycling at := 2^(47)
                                           (     140737488355328)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 47-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=                568434188608080148696899414062500
        | 0x                           1C06A5EC5433C60DDAA16406F5A4
        | 8#                  1600651366124147430156652054401572644
```

---

```
        | 10^48 starts cycling at := 2^(48)
                                           (     281474976710656)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 48-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=               2842170943040400743484497070312500
        | 0x                           8C213D9DA502DE454526F422CC34
        | 8#                 10604117316645005571052122336410546064
```

---

```
        | 10^49 starts cycling at := 2^(49)
                                           (     562949953421312)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 49-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=              14210854715202003717422485351562500
        | 0x                          2BCA63414390E575A59C2C4ADFD04
        | 8#                 53624615012071034535322634130453376404
```

---

```
        | 10^50 starts cycling at := 2^(50)
                                           (    1125899906842624)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 50-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=              71054273576010018587112426757812500
        | 0x                          DAF3F04651D47B4C3C0CDD765F114
        | 8#                332747701062435217323036014672731370424
```

---

```
        | 10^51 starts cycling at := 2^(51)
                                           (    2251799813685248)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 51-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=             355271367880050092935562133789062500
        | 0x                         446C3B15F9926687D2C40534FDB564
        | 8#               2106607305374622315037226100246477332544
```

---

```
        | 10^52 starts cycling at := 2^(52)
                                           (    4503599627370496)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 52-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=            1776356839400250464677810668945312500
        | 0x                        1561D276DDFDC00A71DD41A08F48AF4
        | 8#              12541644733357734001234356501501075105364
```

---

```
        | 10^53 starts cycling at := 2^(53)
                                           (    9007199254740992)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 53-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=            8881784197001252323389053344726562500
        | 0x                        6AE91C5255F4C03439524822CC6B6C4
        | 8#              65351070511257514006416251110105461533304
```

---

```
        | 10^54 starts cycling at := 2^(54)
                                           (   18014398509481984)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 54-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=           44408920985006261616945266723632812500
        | 0x                       2168D8D9BADC7C1051E9B68ADFE191D4
        | 8#             413215433156556174040507515550533770310724
```

---

```
        | 10^55 starts cycling at := 2^(55)
                                           (   36028797018963968)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 55-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=          222044604925031308084726333618164062500
        | 0x                       A70C3C40A64E6C51999090B65F67D924
        | 8#            2470303610051447154243146204413313731754444
```

---

```
        | 10^56 starts cycling at := 2^(56)
                                           (   72057594037927936)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 56-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=         1110223024625156540423631668090820312500
        | 0x                      3433D2D433F881D97FFD2D38FDD073DB4
        | 8#           15031722650317704035457777226470773501636664
```

---

```
        | 10^57 starts cycling at := 2^(57)
                                           (  144115188075855872)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 57-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=         5551115123125782702118158340454101562500
        | 0x                     105031E2503DA893F7FF1E21CF51243484
        | 8#          101201436112017324223757774361034752111032204
```

---

```
        | 10^58 starts cycling at := 2^(58)
                                           (  288230376151711744)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 58-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=        27755575615628913510590791702270507812500
        | 0x                     5190F96B91344AE3D7FB96A90C95B50694
        | 8#          506207626562115045343657756265220622555203224
```

---

```
        | 10^59 starts cycling at := 2^(59)
                                           (  576460752303423488)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 59-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=       138777878078144567552953958511352539062500
        | 0x                    197D4DF19D605767337E9F14D3EEC8920E4
        | 8#         3137246761472601273163157647612323735442220344
```

---

```
        | 10^60 starts cycling at := 2^(60)
                                           ( 1152921504606846976)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 60-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=       693889390390722837764769792556762695312500
        | 0x                    7F7285B812E1B50401791B6823A9EADA474
        | 8#        17734502670045606650100057106664043523653322164
```

---

```
        | 10^61 starts cycling at := 2^(61)
                                           ( 2305843009213693952)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 61-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=      3469446951953614188823848962783813476562500
        | 0x                   27D3C9C985E688914075D8908B2519643644
        | 8#       117517116230274642110500353542204262243131033104
```

---

```
        | 10^62 starts cycling at := 2^(62)
                                           ( 4611686018427387904)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 62-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=     17347234759768070944119244813919067382812500
        | 0x                   C722F0EF9D80AAD6424D3AD2B7B97EF50F54
        | 8#       616213607371660052553102232353225573457675207524
```

---

```
        | 10^63 starts cycling at := 2^(63)
                                           ( 9223372036854775808)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 63-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=     86736173798840354720596224069595336914062500
        | 0x                  3E3AEB4AE1383562F4B82261D969F7AC94CA4
        | 8#      3707272645341160325427513404230354551757262246244
```

---

```
        | 10^64 starts cycling at := 2^(64)
                                           (18446744073709551616)
        | with a powers-of-2 period of
                := 5^( 64-1 ) * ( 5-1 )
                :=    433680868994201773602981120347976684570312500
        | 0x                 13726987666190AEEC798ABE93F11D65EE7F34
        | 8#     23344646073146062053566171425372237421654573477464
```