# Which algorithm python use to calculate a^b%m using pow(a,b,m) so that it is so fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate a^b%m where a,b and m are very large number like 2^256 or 2^512 bit. As far I know some method called bigmod or powmod which calculate a^b%m in O(log m) time complexity but as the number is huge we need to implement it using BigIntegers. Which is slower than normal arithmetic operation. So for this job I have implemented my own Biginteger library and implemented a O(log m) algorithm to calculate a^b%m. But it is using minimum 7-8 seconds to execute where python pow(a,b,m) function is working in less than 1 second. So I want to know the details about the algorithm which is used to implement pow(a,b,m).

Comment: BigIntegers are not a thing in Python. Regular integers will do just fine. What is your question?

Comment: All of CPython is available of github for you to view

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246856/how-did-python-implement-the-built-in-function-pow