# decrypting RSA using c^d mod n

Tags: encryption, rsa, biginteger, bignum, ctf

I'm trying to get a message out of an RSA code, but cant seem to understand
how.
The formula i'm trying to use to find the message is: c^d mod n.
In the text file i received (which is the RSA code), i have 3 parameters:

The c parameter:

```
c=62094327354293714871337806608043143339672711375275261525243238242322194473023610842261452370807533140129255594935713596899492336925573500404508972313463258470764117200138784924348362580128423518572743446058119722861164424364186271770831857887818550880280385895469933434901508250872871673722739401583613920865
```

the N parameter:

```
N=102518413348128616948064302091615267327586561544914497024946023154172320251650248158262401038211060025769143033483116931749752882566368072181993447378932810603880706573407783516535716219705301632360773290434984792276962906314924125193872533986871367036809927042370179209563059349511562287725586162360516841779
```

and the d parameter:

```
d=90575112832191634931822012293951618304193311969935139031973154594700485026947413962490036848108653090804963912366135718482295366073482828257042351498160831683665400283336482471506944874247073018050011183570224881323949477869741822928092177900190031155493051065073868895195339892585741809998466654281718606993
```

Now the problem is that the numbers are WAY too long (308 digits long, and the N parameter is 309 digits long). I couldn't find any calculator that can calculate c^d so far.

any help?

Comment: many languages have easy-to-use support for arbitrary sized integers. For example with python you can solve your problem in about 5 lines of code.

Comment: Although you can't simply exponentiate then mod (even in python); you need to reduce _while_ exponentiating, called modexp or modpow in some langs or libs, but python uses 3-arg pow; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246856/how-did-python-implement-the-built-in-function-pow . Also 'textbook' (unpadded) RSA like you have here is not secure and should never be used except as a throwaway toy or homework, but security issues don't belong in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with java using math.BigInteger

```java
          BigInteger c = new BigInteger("62094327354293714871337806608043143339672711375275261525243238242322194473023610842261452370807533140129255594935713596899492336925573500404508972313463258470764117200138784924348362580128423518572743446058119722861164424364186271770831857887818550880280385895469933434901508250872871673722739401583613920865");
          BigInteger N = new BigInteger("102518413348128616948064302091615267327586561544914497024946023154172320251650248158262401038211060025769143033483116931749752882566368072181993447378932810603880706573407783516535716219705301632360773290434984792276962906314924125193872533986871367036809927042370179209563059349511562287725586162360516841779");
          BigInteger d = new BigInteger("90575112832191634931822012293951618304193311969935139031973154594700485026947413962490036848108653090804963912366135718482295366073482828257042351498160831683665400283336482471506944874247073018050011183570224881323949477869741822928092177900190031155493051065073868895195339892585741809998466654281718606993");
          BigInteger m = new BigInteger("1");
          m = c.modPow(d, N);
          System.out.println(m);
```

And the result would be

```
12095051301478169748702315942951183566712581822646196016924926165965065297342257
```

Comment: Hi Ofek. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try add a bit more explanation to increase the value of the answer to the community. Thank you.

Comment: ... and if you convert that BigInteger to bytes and then ASCII-decode that to a String you will have the OPs answer.