# What is the most efficient way to calculate power of larger numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, rsa

I am working on a cryptography assignment and trying to decrypt an rsa cipher. There is a step in which I calculate

> plaintext = (cipher number) <sup>a</sup>  mod n
>
> ```
> Where a = 39222883199635910704838468978553915708840633543073057195 and 
> n = 68102916241556954755526080258049854830403581949186670592
> cipher number = 49158615403582362779085177062796191820833652424030845810
> ```

When I apply the plain text formula I am supposed to get a small number which will later be used. But this mod line runs for ever and I cannot get an output. For small a and n numbers it works fast. How can I make it work faster?

Here is the part of the code that has to do with my question

```
while True:
    # Get next line from file
    line = fileHandler.readline()
    plaintext = pow(int(line), a) % n
```

Comment: related [How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246856/1820553)

Answer (score 1):

[`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) can actually take 3 arguments for this case:

```py
pow(int(line), a, n)
```

According to the docs:

> ... if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z).

Comment: It would be better if you include the underlying function that is binary exponentiation and the timing comparison from the library link that you gave in to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimized way i found is :

```
pow = (a, b, mod) #where mod is you modulo
```

Example :

```
 mod = 1000000007
    ans = pow(2, n-1, mod) 
    print(ans)
```

This is way faster than using :

```
ans = ((pow(2, n-1) % 1000000007) + 1000000007) % 1000000007 #10 times slower
```