# Can this script have better performance using modular exponentiation?

Tags: python, performance, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return ((a ** b)-1) // c % b
```

Can this script be faster in some way? (I have been looking for something with modular exponentiation):

```
pow(a, b, c) == a ** b % c
```

but this above script doesn't seem to be improvable like that. Does anyone know a way to speedup the above script? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The second script is not at all the same as the first one, it is just meant to show what kind of optimization I had in mind.

Edit:

I didn't put the exact equation in becouse I wanted a general case solution,
the specfics are when a = 4 and c = 3. Does that make it easier?

Edit:

I got the request to make it clear if I want to subtract first or if I want to exponentiate first, I want to first do the exponentiation which I made clear by adding brackets.

Comment: run each case a million times and see the difference

Comment: @DYZ What would you time, though?

Comment: @DYZ But he only has *one* implementation. Are you overlooking the `// c` in what he's asking about?

Comment: I feel that the OP has two implementations: `(a ** b-1) // c % b` and `a ** b % c`. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @DYZ Those are two quite different expressions, they don't compute the same at all. Pretty sure he's just showing the latter together with `pow` to show what kind of improvement he has in mind.

Comment: @HeapOverflow You are right, I tried to show what kind of improvement I had in mind, I know these are very different but they both use exponentiation and I only care about its value modulo a number, they are indeed not the same. I am not a mathematician but maybe one of you is and maybe someone knows a way to speedup the code using for example modular exponentiation.

Comment: Given that almost everyone here misunderstood the question and overlooked what you were really asking about, it would be good if you edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: is it really a bottleneck in your program? if so you should consider using `numpy` if you have a lot of calculations like that, or use Cython, or write Python C/C++ extension, etc., but now your questions looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please clarify whether `a ** b-1` means `a**(b-1)` or `(a**b)-1`.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I think NumPy/Cython etc would be missing the point. Think of `17**123456789 % 13`. If you actually compute `17**123456789` first, it'll be very slow and take a lot of memory. That number is *huge*. But Python's built-in `pow(17, 123456789, 13)` computes the result *instantly*. Because it can reduce `% 13` all the time, keeping intermediary numbers very small. That's not the kind of thing NumPy/Cython are for, is it? And I'd say the goal here is to do `17**123456789 // 23 % 13` similarly efficiently, again without computing `17**123456789` or anything even mildly big.

Comment: @laurensfrensen Just to be sure: Do you really want integer/floor division by c? Or are you actually working modulo b and should be *multiplying* with the *inverse* of c?

Comment: @HeapOverflow: then it can be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com or https://cs.stackexchange.com, because it is just happened to be written in Python, underlying problem seems language independent to me, but there is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246856/how-did-python-implement-the-built-in-function-pow) though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `a**b//c%d == a**b%(c*d)//c%d` holds for any positive integers. This is true because there exists a positive integer `k` such that `a**b == k*c*d + a**b%(c*d)` holds and result of operation `//c%d` over right side is not affected by any `k`. 
According to this fact, `a**b//c%d` can be calculated using a command

```
pow(a,b,c*d)//c%d
```

Comment: Very nice. I had actually guessed this, but somehow dismissed it without even testing it. Silly me :-)

Comment: I think you missed the -1 in the equation as this works without the subtraction but not with it as the -1 is not part of the exponent but it is done after exponentiation, yet this is close.