# python, multiply power of 10 in, strange number

Tags: python

```
(Pdb) int(math.pow(10, num_digits))
100000000000000005366162204393472
(Pdb) num_digits
32
```

When num_digits are big numbers, something is messed up..

Comment: What is your Question? Can you provide some additional information on what you mean with "something is messed up"?

Comment: `math.pow` works with floating point numbers, which have inaccuracies. I think `10**num_digits` would work with integers and would be precise

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov solution should be the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pow with integers use `**`

`n**32`

math.pow uses a float

an explanation about the implementation can be found here : [How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246856/how-did-python-implement-the-built-in-function-pow)